# PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.NEW_SKILL_DESC'

Tags: oracle, triggers, bind

When I run the trigger the  PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.NEW_SKILL_DESC' problems occur. The problem occurs in the: New section. This is the first time I am auditing a database query.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER lds_skill_trig
  BEFORE INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE ON LDS_SKILL
  FOR EACH ROW
ENABLE
DECLARE
  v_user VARCHAR2(30);
  v_date VARCHAR2(30);
BEGIN
  SELECT user, TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'DD/M0N/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') 
  INTO v_user, v_date FROM dual;
    IF INSERTING THEN
      INSERT INTO db_lds_skill(new_skill_desc, old_skill_desc,user_name, 
     entry_date, operation)
    VALUES(:NEW.new_skill_desc, NULL, v_user, v_date, 'Insert');
  ELSIF DELETING THEN
    INSERT INTO db_lds_skill(new_skill_desc, old_skill_desc, user_name, 
     entry_date, operation)
    VALUES(NULL, :OLD.new_skill_desc, v_user, v_date, 'Delete');
  ELSIF UPDATING THEN
    INSERT INTO db_lds_skill(new_skill_desc, old_skill_desc, user_name, 
      entry_date, operation)
    VALUES(:NEW.new_skill_desc, :OLD.new_skill_desc, v_user, v_date,'update');
  END IF;
END;
```

This is the table for db_lds_skill where the audit record i want to save.

```
CREATE TABLE DB_LDS_SKILL
(NEW_SKILL_DESC VARCHAR2(30), 
OLD_SKILL_DESC VARCHAR2(30), 
USER_NAME VARCHAR2(30), 
ENTRY_DATE VARCHAR2(30), 
OPERATION VARCHAR2(30)
);
```

[image]

Comment: Could it be that 'NEW' is doubled redundantly ? I mean, maybe you were going to use ':NEW.SKILL_DESC' instead of 'NEW.NEW_SKILL_DESC'.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have added the create table sytax there.

Comment: @SmileKisan also please add the ddl of `LDS_SKILL`

Comment: @MaximBorunov As you suggested... It didnt solve the problem

Comment: Looks like LDS_SKILL doesn't have a column called `NEW_SKILL_DESC`.

Comment: In addition, you don't need the select from dual; you can just assign the variables directly, e.g. `v_user := user; v_date := sysdate;`

Comment: Storing dates as `VARCHAR2` is always a bad idea.

Comment: You don't need variables, just do `INSERT INTO ...
    VALUES (:NEW.new_skill_desc, NULL, USER, SYSDATE, 'Insert');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are adding wrong column name in the `:NEW.new_skill_desc`, in The `:new.` you have to specific the column for the table `LDS_SKILL` table, not `db_lds_skill`

The below I created locally and it was working fine, Note that I replaced `to_date` with `to_char` and replaced `M0N` with `MON`

```
drop table db_lds_skill
/
create table db_lds_skill 
(new_skill_desc varchar2(100) null,
 old_skill_desc varchar2(100) null,
 user_name varchar2(100) null, 
 entry_date varchar2(100),
 operation varchar2(100) null
)
/
drop table LDS_SKILL
/
create table LDS_SKILL 
(new_skill_desc varchar2(100) null,
 old_skill_desc varchar2(100) null,
 user_name varchar2(100) null, 
 entry_date varchar2(100) nulll,
 operation varchar2(100) null
)
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER lds_skill_trig
  BEFORE INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE ON LDS_SKILL
  FOR EACH ROW
ENABLE
DECLARE
  v_user VARCHAR2(30);
  v_date VARCHAR2(30);
BEGIN
  SELECT user, TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') 
  INTO v_user, v_date FROM dual;
    IF INSERTING THEN
      INSERT INTO db_lds_skill(new_skill_desc, old_skill_desc,user_name, 
     entry_date, operation)
    VALUES(:NEW.new_skill_desc, NULL, v_user, v_date, 'Insert');
  ELSIF DELETING THEN
    INSERT INTO db_lds_skill(new_skill_desc, old_skill_desc, user_name, 
     entry_date, operation)
    VALUES(NULL, :OLD.new_skill_desc, v_user, v_date, 'Delete');
  ELSIF UPDATING THEN
    INSERT INTO db_lds_skill(new_skill_desc, old_skill_desc, user_name, 
      entry_date, operation)
    VALUES(:NEW.new_skill_desc, :OLD.new_skill_desc, v_user, v_date,'update');
  END IF;
END;
/
insert into LDS_SKILL (new_skill_desc) values('pp')
/
commit
/
```

Comment: You turned the OP's `to_char(sysdate, ...)` into `to_date(sysdate, ...)` ... I assume this was a typo? You should **NEVER** use `to_date` on something that's already a date!

Comment: @Boneist i agree but if he want to specific the format of the date , wouldn't he use also the TO_DATE ?

Comment: @Moudiz If something is of DATE datatype, it is already in Oracle's internal date format. If you wish to display it (or use it elsewhere) in a specific format, then you must use `to_char` to convert it into a string of that particular format. Otherwise, just leave it alone.

Comment: @Boneist okay thanks for your advice , I edit my question taking on condition his table strucute `entry_date` as a varchar2